# Thread access on GUI controls

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

my topic is pretty much the question. I know that there limitations from a thread to access GUI controls. It seems that writing/setting something in a control from another thread other that the main thread is not possible.

But for example when I try to read whether a checkbox is checked it works. Reading a combobox's text won't.

I am using windows forms with .net framework 4.

Can someone tell me where the limitations for threads are?

Comment: what UI framework are you asking for?

Comment: The immediate exceptions are a Debug feature. Reading a CheckBox is not necessarily safe. The limits are: The _entire_ GUI is not thread-safe.

Comment: @Servy this is not an excapt duplicate, because he is asking for a change to the ui. I stated that I know that changig is bad, but I was not sure for reading

Comment: @derape The answer is the same, for the same reasons, so I consider it close enough to be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UI elements can only be updated on the UI thread - you can check if [invoke required](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) to let you know if you're on another thread.

Here's a similar question you might like [When is invoke required on GUI objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554981/when-is-invoke-required-on-gui-objects)

Comment: Thanks, I was asking for a more general answer. So I guess there isn't. Even though I'm not explicitly trying to WRITE the UI, even reading is in general not a good idea I guess, even if it works!?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on it working, no

Comment: you might like this link too - where the answer says 'it's possible (to read values) but could lead to unexpected behaviour - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975938/is-it-possible-to-access-a-ui-element-from-another-thread-if-the-thread-doesnt

Comment: ah thanks, couldn't find that post, that answers my question too. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You must be on the *UI thread* whenever you access a UI element. What you observed doesn't depend on whether the control is a checkbox or a dropdown, but from which thread you are accessing.

Windows Forms Controls provide the `Invoke` method dispatch a call to the UI thread. There is also an *async* [`BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx). Async invocations might speed up your system (depending on your design).

There is an article on the *Dispatcher* in WPF: [Build More Responsive Apps With The Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke an action to do something with UI, but it is only needed when you need to access something from your worker thread.

```
void UpdateMessage (string message)
{
  Action action = () => txtMessage.Text = message;
  this.Invoke (action);
}
```

[This is a really good resource about threading](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)